# Как вложить один файл в другой, то есть .xlsx в .docx. Подскажите библиотечку или способ)

Tags: java, excel, ms-word, apache-poi

Я создаю два файла excel и word, в них записываю инфу, все это проделываю с помощью Apache POI. Теперь мне необходимо вложить первый файл во второй, но я не знаю как.

Подскажите, как закодить именно этот процесс?

Comment: 1 - бегите от этих форматов файлов!!  2 - Если всё-таки необходимо вставлять таблицу в doc или наоборот: придётся изучить всю спецификацию COM по excel и word

Comment: 1 - почему бежать?) к сожалению, не могу ( код уже работает в продакшн.
2 - Попросили прикрутить эту тему с вложением.

А что за COM?)

Comment: это внешние интерфейсы microsoft, для взаимодействия с файлами в данном случае xlsx или doc (и пр.) из других программ